# Duplicating Categories

Tags: magento2, category, category-tree

I am trying to set up a new website which has been migrated from an older site.

This migration carried over the old category structure.

Within the new structure i want to build, I am creating new root categories for different store views. I want to copy some of the categories into multiple store view Root categories.

Is this possible and if so how can i achieve this?

when i click on a sub category, my only options are `Save` and `Delete`.

I am trying to do this in `Magento 2.2.4`

Comment: It is not possible to assign root categories on store views. You can only do this on store level.